# how to call plist file in Document folder

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist

I to create plist file in Document folder and I want call and store data in NSDictionary but I dont know to use of what syntax???

my plist file is Dictionary type.

this is my code:

```
#define DOC_DIR [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]

     NSString *item = @"Content";
        array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        for (int i =0; i<8; i++) {
            [array addObject:item];
        }
        NSLog(@"array : %@",array);
        [self WriteDataToPlistFromArray:array];
    - (void)WriteDataToPlistFromArray:(NSArray*)dataArray
    {
        NSDictionary *dic = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:dataArray,@"Root", nil];
        NSString *Path = [DOC_DIR stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"mamal.plist"];
        [dic writeToFile:Path atomically:YES];
        NSLog(@"%@",dic);
        NSLog(@"%@",Path);
    }
I want call plist from Document Folder and show data in it.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access your plist do like this

```
NSArray *directoryPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSDocumentDirectory,    NSUserDomainMask ,YES ) objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *filePath = [directoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"mamal.plist"];
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSLog(@"File content : %@",dict);
```

Comment: When ever you required data from plist write this code.  Anywhere you can use this to retrieve data

Comment: my friend I put this code in one function with name (ReadDataFromPlist) and call this function from viewDidLoad with code [self ReadDataFromPlist] but dict is null.

Comment: Did you write the plist properly.. Can you find it in the document directory? I mean in the app installed folder

Answer (score 1):

The value of `DOC_DIR` should be:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSDocumentDirectory,    NSUserDomainMask ,YES );
NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

i.e. your code can be re-written as:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSDocumentDirectory,    NSUserDomainMask ,YES );
NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *Path = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"mamal.plist"];
[dic writeToFile:Path atomically:YES];
```

Comment: my friend I want call mamal.plist another place and read data from and I dont know what I do?